# How to prevent floats form moving between a paragraph and an align?

Tags: latex, figure, pdflatex, amsmath

In my document I talk about a calculation and then I do all the equations. So I would like to have those next to each other. Unfortunately some floats really make life difficult.

I have the folowing latex code:

```
  [Some Paragraph]

    \begin{table}
      ... This is a small table (4rows)
    \end{table}

    \begin{table}
      ... This table spans almost a page
    \end{table}

    \begin{figure}
      ... This figure spans half a page
    \end{figure}


    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
    THIS PARAGRAP REFERS TO THE CALCULATION BELOW AND SHOULD BE FOLLOWED IMMEDIATELY BY THE CALCULATION.
    %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

    \begin{align*}
      ... This is the CALCULATION.
    \end{align*}
```

The result is that all the tables and figures slide between the PARAGRAPH and the CALCULATION.

I could fix every Figure with the **[H]** parameter but that's not what I really want to do. Instead I want to prevent anything from sliding between my PARAGRAPH and my CALCULATION

**How is it possible to prevent floats from getting between a paragraph and an align?**

Comment: Can you make a [mre] that actually reproduces your problem? Just a guess: removing the empty line between the paragraph and the align might already help

Comment: I am surprised, but removing the line worked. (I had tried it before but then it didn't do the trick. By now I have continued writing my dissertation and removing the empty line actually helped. Thanks!

(I'm not really happy about sharing anything since it is from my dissertation)

Comment: You should be careful with empty lines before equations, they are almost always wrong and will result in incorrect vertical spacing. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/89518